# How to press button in webpage ( chrome browser ) with autoit?

Tags: autoit

I'm trying to do an automatic search engine in google. 
But i dont know how to press button in webpage. `ShellExecute("https://www.google.bg/")
MouseMove(751,401)
MouseClick("left", 751, 401, 1)
Send("hello world")`

And now I want to press the search button.

Comment: Why not cut out the middle man, and just call `ShellExecute("https://www.google.bg/?gws_rd=ssl#q=hello+world")` ?

Comment: This is just an example, it is not the real code. The problem is by pressing the button

Comment: I've only used AutoHotkey, rather than AutoIt. As browser buttons aren't real windowing components, for tasks like this I've either used 1) calling the target URL with GET params; 2) wget scripts for POST options; 3) clicking the X/Y position within the window (fails on liquid layouts, browser toolbars changing, etc); 4) Searching the window for the position of a specific color or screengrabbed image of the button; 5) a GreaseMonkey script instead.  None is a good answer to this question, but I offer them as possible workarounds if you get no real answers.

Comment: if you open the google search page, the focus is already on the input field. Why MouseMove/MouseClick? And just `send({ENTER})` instead of searching for a button and click on it.